# Credentials of a folder: Only Allow access to a Program

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, permissions

We have an Access made application that runs in a workgroup. All the users in the workgroup can gain access to the folder where the app is located.

Our aim is to don't allow users to see, read or write in the folder, but at the same time allow the Access application to get into the folder in order to read, write or copy the files there located.

So, it's possible to grant access to a folder only for a specific application and not for the user that runs that application?

Comment: Windows permissions don’t work this way.  An application has the same permissions (lowest possible in the case of an Administrator unless its elevated), if the users don’t have read or write permissions neither would the application.  This basic behavior cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible.

But you can run the app under another user account. See the [RunAs command](https://ss64.com/nt/runas.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is standard Windows functionality.

Access right are based on users, not applications.

System security is for the user, for example, some computers have multiple users. When logging in, they will be prompted to select a user. After logging in, the user's permissions are clear. Some software and the system's own policies can also restrict a folder from being accessed, but this is global, at most for the user, not for the program.

We can however run the programs as different users. From the context menu (hold the **Shift** + Right Mouse click on the program) select **Run as different user**. We will need different user accounts with the correct access control settings to the folders based on the users.